# Reading production.log files from a few days ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

Any way to read production.log files for a few days ago for a rails app?

I been only doing this and it's not effective:

```
tail log/*
tail -f log/production.log
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the day, you can just grep for the appropriate dates:

```
grep --after-context 200 2014-06-02 log/production.log | less
```

The `--after-context 200` option is used because rails does not include the date in every line, so we output the matching line and the following 200 lines, which should be enough.

Replace `2014-06-02` by your wanted date, obviously.

You can also state the hour or minutes like this:

```
grep --after-context 200 '2014-06-02 22:46' log/production.log | less
```

**If you dont know the date**, then you can just use tail with the `-n` parameter. For example, this outputs the log from the 100st line:

```
tail -n +100 log/production.log | less
```

so just change the `+100` parameter until you get what you want.

Comment: Can i output more than 200 lines? Cause even when I do 200, it only outputs about 50 -- just had to scroll down....

Comment: I added `less` to the end of the command, which allows you to scroll in the output: http://linux.die.net/man/1/less. If you dont want this, just leave `| less` from the end.

Answer (score 2):

I would `less` it, then search for a line with the timestamp i want.

```
#in the console 
less log/production.log
```

Once you're in less, hit the forward-slash then type `at 2014-06-01` and hit enter.  It should search through till it hits the first request made on that date.